# Why is page content not showing in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hey I'm struggling with this problem.

**This is App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'

const App = () => {
   return(
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact></Route>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**This is Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello from home page</h1>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**This is About.js**

```
const About = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello from about page</h1>
  )
}

export default About
```

After this all code content is not showing in on the home page and about page!!

Answer (score 1):

In version 6 they changed the way you pass the components to the routes. You now use the element prop and also use the angled brackets around the component name. 
[Referring to the exact docs for configuring routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#configuring-routes).

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'

const App = () => {
   return(
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```